# Running Bash Script in a Browser Even with Apache Permissions Set

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, php, docker

I have a program that sits in a Docker container. I want to be able to go to a browser page and run the Docker container so the program will start.

So, I created a bash script that runs the Docker command (**runcontainer.sh**):

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix myproject
```

Then I created a PHP file that runs that shell script (**webscript.php**):

```
<?php
    exec('/usr/lib/cgi-bin/runcontainer.sh');
?>
```

I am running ubuntu 16.04 with apache2 installed.

**Problem:**
The program runs if I run `php webscript.php` in a bash terminal. The container starts, and the program starts. However, if I try from the web browser (firefox), it doesn't.

I go to http://localhost/cgi-bin/webscript.php, I see the page, but the Docker container never starts. So, I looked at /var/log/apache2/error.log, and saw this error: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.

Based on similar questions, I ran  `sudo apachectl -S` to see the name of apache user and group. It is www-data for both. So, I set the user and group to the /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ directory to www-data.

Even with www-data having full permissions, I still see the `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` error. Other answers I've found say to change the sudoers file to give www-data ALL access. I didn't want to do that though because it seems unsafe.

Comment: @Jesse_b Note that allowing `www-data` to become root is generally a _big_ security risk.

Comment: @Jesse_b I tried it just to see if it would work. I added `%www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/lib/cgi-bin` to the bottom of my /etc/sudoers script and restarted the apache server with `service apache2 restart`, I got the same tty error.

Answer (score 1):

I performed few experiments (using Cron instead of Apache and `/bin/ls` instead of `runcontainer.sh`) to reproduce error message you encountered. Based on that, I suggest you first verify whether `www-data` can run your intended command without password.

To check if you can run command without password, login as root user and then

```
# su - -s /bin/bash www-data
$ sudo /usr/lib/cgi-bin/runcontainer.sh
```

Also, You should also check `/etc/sudoers` whether you have enabled `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/runcontainer.sh` for `www-data` user.

```
%www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/runcontainer.sh
```

If above works, we can focus on next level.